# How to configure activemq embedded broker to accept Json post

Tags: java, json, activemq-classic, broker

I am initializing an activeMQ embedded broker as follows:

```
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
broker.addConnector("http://localhost:8161");
broker.start();
```

Then I perform some posts of Json Strings to the following URL to use the REST capabilities of ActiveMQ:

```
"http://localhost:8161/api/message/EventQueue?type=queue"
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not s (position: START_DOCUMENT seen s... @1:1)
```

I think maybe some configuration is required for the embedded broker to work with Json, but I could not find information about that in the activeMQ help.

Many thanks!

Comment: You have configured a TCP connector in this code and are sending HTTP to it, not going to work.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I pasted the wrong code, but I am using http in my actual code. I edited already the question with my actual code. So any thoughts?